# Simulating ADTs in Java

Tags: java, haskell, algebraic-data-types

An application may operate in two modes - "real time" where it looks at every update to the state of the world, or "sampled" where it only looks at the state of the world every T milliseconds.

If I were writing Haskell (or any language with ADTs) I would model this as

```hs
data Mode = RealTime | Sampled Int
```

which can be used as follows in a type-safe way

```hs
case mode of
    RealTime         -> -- do realtime stuff
    Sampled interval -> -- do sample stuff with 'interval'
```

I say that it is "type-safe" because if you are running in real-time mode, you are prevented from trying to access the `interval` field (which is provided at just the time you need it if you are operating in sampled mode).

How can I model the same thing in Java in a type-safe way? That is, I want

- To define a class (or enum) that distinguishes between the two modes, and
- To prohibit access to the `interval` field when in real-time mode, and
- To have all of this checked by the compiler.

Is this possible in Java? If not, what is the idiomatic way to achieve this kind of type-safety?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The traditional way to emulate closed algebraic data types in a language like Java that only provides open classes (that can be inherited anytime) in a type-safe way is the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern):

```
abstract class Mode {
    public abstract <T> T accept(ModeVisitor<T> visitor);
}

final class RealTime extends Mode {
    public RealTime() {}

    public <T> T accept(ModeVisitor<T> visitor) {
        return visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

final class Sampled extends Mode {
    private final int interval;

    public Sampled(int interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    public int getInterval() {
        return this.interval;
    }

    public <T> T accept(ModeVisitor<T> visitor) {
        return visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

// The recursion principle itself
abstract class ModeVisitor<T> {
    public abstract T visit(RealTime mode);
    public abstract T visit(Sampled mode);
}

// Concrete uses of the recursion principle
final class ModeShow extends ModeVisitor<String> {
    private ModeShow() {}

    public static String show(Mode mode) {
        return mode.accept(new ModeShow());
    }

    public String visit(RealTime mode) {
        return "RealTime";
    }

    public String visit(Sampled mode) {
        return "Sampled " + mode.getInterval();
    }
}
```

As @user3237465 remarked, several encodings of data types are possible, which *happen* to coincide when the data type isn't recursive: The Church encoding is a fold: it allows you to accumulate a value by recursion over the Church-encoded datatype. The Scott encoding corresponds to actual pattern matching. In any case, visitors can be used to implement all of these encodings. Thanks for the nudge, @user3237465!

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the best way to go. Can we avoid defining the `ModeVisitor` class in Java 8 by using lambdas instead (eg `public <T> accept(Function<Mode, T> visitor)`) or do you lose something by doing that?

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: You need the visitor, because the `visit` method itself is overloaded, and each `Mode` subclass has to select its corresponding overload.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: A concrete visitor actually can be thought as a package containing *several* lambdas: one for each ADT variant. Visitors are analogous to the result of applying the `maybe` and `either` functions (from Haskell's standard library) to two arguments: `maybe foo bar` will use `foo` to visit `Nothing` and `bar` to visit `Just x`.

Comment: Church encoding is just a hack for those, who don't have adequate mechanism for defining data types, because primitive recursion is [too weak](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397591900395). ADTs are OK, everything that resembles Scott encoding (paramorphisms, dependent eliminators, Scott encoding itself) is OK, Church encoding is not OK.

Comment: @user3237465: I don't disagree that Church encodings are a hack. But, does Java give you anything better for this situation?

Comment: @Eduardo León, I don't know Java, so I can't tell. But I feel like you use Scott encoding actually. In the `data Mode = RealTime | Sampled Int` case these two are equivalent, but the encodings differ for recursive data types. Church-encoded lists are `newtype Church a = Church { runChurch :: forall r. (a -> r       -> r) -> r -> r }`, Scott-encoded lists are `newtype Scott  a = Scott  { runScott  :: forall r. (a -> Scott a -> r) -> r -> r }`. Am I right, that you use the second representation?

Comment: @user3237465: Let me see if I understand correctly. The Scott encoding ensures that the tail is also a Scott-encoded list, right? (By the way, if you're on Freenode, we can continue the discussion there. My nick is pyon, and I'm in #haskell.)

Comment: @Eduardo León, yes the tail of a Scott-encoded list is also a Scott-encoded list. I don't know what Freenode is, but we can go to [the Java chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java) at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare an interface `Mode`

```
public interface Mode {
    void doSmth();
}
```

And then you can have two classes implementing that interface

```
public class Realtime implements Mode {
    @Override
    public void doSmth() {
        // Do realtime stuff
    }
}

public class Sampled implements Mode {
    private final int interval;

    public Sampled(final int interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    @Override
    public void doSmth() {
        // Do sampled stuff
    }
}
```

Then you declare a variable of type `Mode`

```
final Mode mode = ... // Initialize however you want, calling one of the constructors.
```

And then, since `mode` is of type `Mode`, you will only be able to access what's declared in the interface. So you can just call `mode.doSmth()` and, depending on how you initialized `mode`, it will run realtime or sampled.

If the classes share some code, then you can declare an `abstract` class instead of an `interface`, and have both classes `extend` that class. So then they can call the common methods that are declared in the `abstract` class (which should be declared with `protected` visibility, so that only subclasses can see them)

Comment: It seems like this forces me to put the behaviour *inside* the `Mode` implementations, is that correct? What if I have various code paths that want to do different things based on the mode? In fact, this is part of a library, so users of the library need to be able to add their own behaviours for different modes.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor Java 8 supports passing functions as parameters. So instead of declaring a no-arg method. You can declare a function that receives the actual task to be done. So then `RealTime` will just call that function constantly and `Sampled` will call it every x seconds or whatever. Another approach could be declaring a couple of methods `ifRealTime(f)` and `ifSampled(f)` to the interface and in the concrete implementations, the `RealTime` will call the function in `ifRealTime` and do nothing in `ifSampled`. Hope I made myself clear

Comment: The principle of _abstraction_ is to design an interface (or abstract class) which encapsulates completely all possible behaviours concerning a funcionality. So, if there are several points in your code that depend on how is this funcionality implemented, each one of them deserves a proper _method_ in that interface.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of corse it is possible, altough it dependes on the level of complexity you are ready to achieve.

If you want to achieve the highest level of type-safeness, I recommend you to declare an *abstraction* (named `AbstractModeManager`) which responsibility will be to query the state of the world and store it in instance variables, which should be accesible through public getter methods. And it must also know when there has been an update:

```
abstract class AbstractModeManager
{
    // Instance variables to contain the last state read.
    private ... state;

    protected void queryTheStateOfTheWorld(...) throws ...
    {
        ... fill this.state ...
    }

    public ... getState()
    {
        return this.state;
    }

    public abstract void updateOccurred(...);
}
```

Under that, you must code two implementations: One for the real time, and another for the sampled:

```
class RealTimeModeManager extends AbstractModeManager
{
    public void updateOccurred(...)
    {
        // In this implementation, every time there has been an update, 
        // a query must be performed:
        queryTheStateOfTheWorld(...);
    }
}

class SampledModeManager extends AbstractModeManager
{
    public SampledModeManager(int interval)
    {
        ... program a timer to call the queryTheStateOfTheWorld ...
    }

    public void updateOccurred(...)
    {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

And last, you have to decide which of them must be used in each case, store it in a variable:

```
private AbstractModeManager mode=...
```

... And invoke *systematically* it at every update in the system:

```
mode.updateOccurred(...)
```

In this way, after initializing that variable, you won't care which mode the system is running: That behaviour is left to your *abstraction*.

Comment: This doesn't cover how one could define arbitrary functions by case analysis on `Mode`s, without modifying the `Mode`s themselves. Which is the whole point to [algebraic data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type).

Comment: Yes, you are right: That is because I preferred to focus on the abstraction pattern. For that matter, the visitor pattern you have proposed is a good choice, and also the listener pattern.